# Import csv from web

Tags: html, r, url, web, export

In the following url

```
 http://www.indiavotes.com/ac/details/1/32051/216
```

There is link to "EXPORT to CSV", but I could find neither table info nor download.csv link in pagesource().

How can I download this csv using R?

Comment: Selenium + HTML table scrape or intercept the http request parameters of the POST request it makes. They go to _alot_ of trouble to make it difficult to get data from that site in an automated fashion.

Comment: okay .. is there any way I can think of or I can try

Comment: Sorry if this can't be more helpful. I tried a bunch of things using R; I didn't make much progress. I'm definitely NOT and R expert. There is probably a way to do this using R, but I couldn't figure it out. I have a VBA solution for you, if that's ok.  Run the script below, and you'll get your data-dump. Then, parse the data and save it as a CSV file. That should be pretty easy. Post back if you need more help with this.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub DumpData()

Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Visible = True

URL = "http://www.indiavotes.com/ac/details/1/32051/216"

'Wait for site to fully load
IE.Navigate2 URL
Do While IE.Busy = True
   DoEvents
Loop

RowCount = 1

With Sheets("Sheet1")
   .Cells.ClearContents
   RowCount = 1
   For Each itm In IE.document.all
      .Range("A" & RowCount) = itm.tagname
      .Range("B" & RowCount) = itm.ID
      .Range("C" & RowCount) = itm.classname
      .Range("D" & RowCount) = Left(itm.innertext, 1024)

      RowCount = RowCount + 1
   Next itm
End With
End Sub
```